# Can Azure Application Insights be used on applications not hosted in Azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure-application-insights

Is it possible for me to add Application Insights to a .NET application that we host in our local environment for monitoring within Azure, or does Application Insights only work for applications hosted on Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor *any kind of app anywhere* with Application Insights, as long as the thing being monitored can send outbound telemetry to application insights.  the ip addresses for application insights [are documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-ip-addresses) if this requires setting up any kind of firewall/etc rules.

Azure is the "storage location" for your telemetry.  Your app doesn't have to *run* in Azure, or even be a web app.  people use application insights for console apps, device apps powershell scripts, web apps hosted all over the place, etc.